# parse_long declared in header but not defined

Tags: c, function, header, undefined

I have few parsing functions declared in a header, but I couldn't find their definitions anywhere in the code. I could find calls, but no definitions. Are they part of some predefined library? I tried to google that but nothing related came up.

Functions such as:

```
int parse_ulong(const char *str, unsigned long *ul);
int parse_long(const char *str, long *ul);
int parse_u32(const char *str, uint32_t *ul);
```

Comment: I know of no platform or framework where functions like that are standard. Where did you get the header file from? How did you learn about it? What is it named? Please give us more details.

Comment: I am trying to analyze the OpenOCD code. the header I am talking about is available in this link https://github.com/ntfreak/openocd/blob/master/src/helper/command.h and the definition of these functions are not available anywhere else in the openocd code

Comment: You *did* look in the [`command.c`](https://github.com/ntfreak/openocd/blob/master/src/helper/command.c) source file?

Comment: I think these are defined in `command.c` via macro definition of DEFINE_PARSE_NUM_TYPE. So for example `DEFINE_PARSE_NUM_TYPE(_ulong, unsigned long, strtoul, 0, ULONG_MAX)` this should define parse_ulong.